# Failing to start FastAPI server, error in asyncpg

Tags: docker, python-asyncio, fastapi, asyncpg, tortoise-orm

EDIT: turns out there was quite a few different errors. If you run into similar problems, you probably misconfigured something in your database - like exposing wrong port somewhere along the way.

This is my first time using pretty much every piece of the stack here. I'm not sure what's relevant, so I'll try to provide all the information.

I'm building FastAPI app with attached Postgres db on DigitalOcean droplet via docker-compose. It was running fine on my local machine, but it fails to run on DigitalOcean (it failed in the same way on AWS, so I'm guessing it's not server issue).

Here's Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8

EXPOSE 7000

RUN pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install torch==1.6.0+cpu torchvision==0.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

RUN pip install fastapi[all] passlib[bcrypt] transformers[torch] python-jose[cryptography] tortoise-orm fastapi-users[tortoise-orm,oauth] databases[postgresql] python-multipart aiofiles jinja2 asyncpg aiomysql aiosqlite sentence-transformers numpy

COPY ./app /app

CMD uvicorn --host=0.0.0.0 app.main:app
```

Here's docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=XX
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=XX
      - POSTGRES_DB=XX
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  web:
    restart: always
    container_name: DiscuSearchFastAPI
    build: .
    ports:
      - "7000:7000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    networks:
      - mynetwork
networks:
  mynetwork:
    driver: bridge
```

After copying files and installing docker on droplet (Ubuntu 20), here's whole console:

```
root@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-nyc1-01:~/DiscuSearch# docker-compose build && docker-compose up
db uses an image, skipping
Building web
Step 1/7 : FROM python:3.8
3.8: Pulling from library/python
e4c3d3e4f7b0: Pull complete
101c41d0463b: Pull complete
8275efcd805f: Pull complete
751620502a7a: Pull complete
0a5e725150a2: Pull complete
397dba5694db: Pull complete
b453803265bc: Pull complete
a49354af7e01: Pull complete
7f7c8879a275: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:5b1dc84f5b565ef0a12c093734e76dc7fef2825d7713f90cc5634e1b32c21af1
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.8
 ---> f5e423f5ce1f
Step 2/7 : EXPOSE 7000
 ---> Running in ec2b5988704d
Removing intermediate container ec2b5988704d
 ---> 94bce661d81c
Step 3/7 : RUN pip install --upgrade pip
 ---> Running in fb4b28bd0cb5
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.2.4)
Removing intermediate container fb4b28bd0cb5
 ---> e2797c69d3ad
Step 4/7 : RUN pip install torch==1.6.0+cpu torchvision==0.7.0+cpu -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
 ---> Running in 55edfe50a939
Looking in links: https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
Collecting torch==1.6.0+cpu
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.6.0%2Bcpu-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl (154.6 MB)
Collecting torchvision==0.7.0+cpu
  Downloading https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torchvision-0.7.0%2Bcpu-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl (5.1 MB)
Collecting numpy
  Downloading numpy-1.19.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (14.9 MB)
Collecting future
  Downloading future-0.18.2.tar.gz (829 kB)
Collecting pillow>=4.1.1
  Downloading Pillow-8.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.2 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: future
  Building wheel for future (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for future (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for future: filename=future-0.18.2-py3-none-any.whl size=491059 sha256=ca73a489be9ae0b4b5736d9162d2cbd2138ccc5f624d7e4bcb7513b2e8971a2b
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8e/70/28/3d6ccd6e315f65f245da085482a2e1c7d14b90b30f239e2cf4
Successfully built future
Installing collected packages: numpy, future, torch, pillow, torchvision
Successfully installed future-0.18.2 numpy-1.19.3 pillow-8.0.1 torch-1.6.0+cpu torchvision-0.7.0+cpu
Removing intermediate container 55edfe50a939
 ---> dc94dba1f82c
Step 5/7 : RUN pip install fastapi[all] passlib[bcrypt] transformers[torch] python-jose[cryptography] tortoise-orm fastapi-users[tortoise-orm,oauth] databases[postgresql] python-multipart aiofiles jinja2 asyncpg aiomysql aiosqlite sentence-transformers numpy
 ---> Running in 495de7e00ea1
Collecting fastapi[all]
  Downloading fastapi-0.61.1-py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Collecting passlib[bcrypt]
  Downloading passlib-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (525 kB)
Collecting transformers[torch]
  Downloading transformers-3.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting python-jose[cryptography]
  Downloading python_jose-3.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (26 kB)
Collecting tortoise-orm
  Downloading tortoise-orm-0.16.17.tar.gz (94 kB)
Collecting fastapi-users[oauth,tortoise-orm]
  Downloading fastapi_users-3.0.6-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting databases[postgresql]
  Downloading databases-0.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting python-multipart
  Downloading python-multipart-0.0.5.tar.gz (32 kB)
Collecting aiofiles
  Downloading aiofiles-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting jinja2
  Downloading Jinja2-2.11.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Collecting asyncpg
  Downloading asyncpg-0.21.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.9 MB)
Collecting aiomysql
  Downloading aiomysql-0.0.20-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
Collecting aiosqlite
  Downloading aiosqlite-0.16.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting sentence-transformers
  Downloading sentence-transformers-0.3.8.tar.gz (66 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (1.19.3)
Collecting pydantic<2.0.0,>=1.0.0
  Downloading pydantic-1.7.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (12.2 MB)
Collecting starlette==0.13.6
  Downloading starlette-0.13.6-py3-none-any.whl (59 kB)
Collecting orjson<4.0.0,>=3.2.1; extra == "all"
  Downloading orjson-3.4.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (232 kB)
Collecting uvicorn<0.12.0,>=0.11.5; extra == "all"
  Downloading uvicorn-0.11.8-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
Collecting async_exit_stack<2.0.0,>=1.0.1; extra == "all"
  Downloading async_exit_stack-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (4.7 kB)
Collecting email_validator<2.0.0,>=1.1.1; extra == "all"
  Downloading email_validator-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting graphene<3.0.0,>=2.1.8; extra == "all"
  Downloading graphene-2.1.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (107 kB)
Collecting pyyaml<6.0.0,>=5.3.1; extra == "all"
  Downloading PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)
Collecting requests<3.0.0,>=2.24.0; extra == "all"
  Downloading requests-2.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Collecting ujson<4.0.0,>=3.0.0; extra == "all"
  Downloading ujson-3.2.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (181 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous<2.0.0,>=1.1.0; extra == "all"
  Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting async_generator<2.0.0,>=1.10; extra == "all"
  Downloading async_generator-1.10-py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting bcrypt>=3.1.0; extra == "bcrypt"
  Downloading bcrypt-3.2.0-cp36-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (63 kB)
Collecting regex!=2019.12.17
  Downloading regex-2020.10.28-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (679 kB)
Collecting tqdm>=4.27
  Downloading tqdm-4.51.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (70 kB)
Collecting filelock
  Downloading filelock-3.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting protobuf
  Downloading protobuf-3.13.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting sentencepiece!=0.1.92
  Downloading sentencepiece-0.1.94-cp38-cp38-manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (1.1 MB)
Collecting packaging
  Downloading packaging-20.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting sacremoses
  Downloading sacremoses-0.0.43.tar.gz (883 kB)
Collecting tokenizers==0.9.2
  Downloading tokenizers-0.9.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.9 MB)
Requirement already satisfied: torch>=1.0; extra == "torch" in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from transformers[torch]) (1.6.0+cpu)
Collecting ecdsa<0.15
  Downloading ecdsa-0.14.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
Collecting six<2.0
  Downloading six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pyasn1
  Downloading pyasn1-0.4.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Collecting rsa
  Downloading rsa-4.6-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting cryptography; extra == "cryptography"
  Downloading cryptography-3.2.1-cp35-abi3-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (2.6 MB)
Collecting pypika>=0.39.0
  Downloading pypika-0.43.0.tar.gz (60 kB)
Collecting iso8601>=0.1.12
  Downloading iso8601-0.1.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=3.7
  Downloading typing_extensions-3.7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Collecting aerich>=0.3.2
  Downloading aerich-0.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting makefun<1.10,>=1.9.2
  Downloading makefun-1.9.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting pyjwt==1.7.1
  Downloading PyJWT-1.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting httpx-oauth<0.4,>=0.3; extra == "oauth"
  Downloading httpx_oauth-0.3.4-py3-none-any.whl (9.8 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.3.20-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
Collecting psycopg2; extra == "postgresql"
  Downloading psycopg2-2.8.6.tar.gz (383 kB)
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (32 kB)
Collecting PyMySQL<=0.9.2,>=0.9
  Downloading PyMySQL-0.9.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Collecting scikit-learn
  Downloading scikit_learn-0.23.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (6.8 MB)
Collecting scipy
  Downloading scipy-1.5.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (25.8 MB)
Collecting nltk
  Downloading nltk-3.5.zip (1.4 MB)
Collecting uvloop>=0.14.0; sys_platform != "win32" and sys_platform != "cygwin" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
  Downloading uvloop-0.14.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (4.7 MB)
Collecting websockets==8.*
  Downloading websockets-8.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (78 kB)
Collecting click==7.*
  Downloading click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Collecting h11<0.10,>=0.8
  Downloading h11-0.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting httptools==0.1.*; sys_platform != "win32" and sys_platform != "cygwin" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"
  Downloading httptools-0.1.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (227 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0.0
  Downloading idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting dnspython>=1.15.0
  Downloading dnspython-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (208 kB)
Collecting graphql-relay<3,>=2
  Downloading graphql_relay-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (20 kB)
Collecting aniso8601<=7,>=3
  Downloading aniso8601-7.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (42 kB)
Collecting graphql-core<3,>=2.1
  Downloading graphql_core-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (252 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Downloading certifi-2020.6.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2
  Downloading chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Downloading urllib3-1.25.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.1
  Downloading cffi-1.14.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (410 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from protobuf->transformers[torch]) (50.3.2)
Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting joblib
  Downloading joblib-0.17.0-py3-none-any.whl (301 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: future in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from torch>=1.0; extra == "torch"->transformers[torch]) (0.18.2)
Collecting httpx<0.17,>=0.15
  Downloading httpx-0.16.1-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Collecting threadpoolctl>=2.0.0
  Downloading threadpoolctl-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Collecting promise<3,>=2.2
  Downloading promise-2.3.tar.gz (19 kB)
Collecting rx<2,>=1.6
  Downloading Rx-1.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (179 kB)
Collecting pycparser
  Downloading pycparser-2.20-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112 kB)
Collecting httpcore==0.12.*
  Downloading httpcore-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
Collecting rfc3986[idna2008]<2,>=1.3
  Downloading rfc3986-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting sniffio
  Downloading sniffio-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: tortoise-orm, python-multipart, sentence-transformers, pyyaml, sacremoses, pypika, psycopg2, nltk, promise
  Building wheel for tortoise-orm (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for tortoise-orm (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for tortoise-orm: filename=tortoise_orm-0.16.17-py3-none-any.whl size=108764 sha256=3c59fa9be2043e0a283f0ba0aa90762ab45e3e873054956a614ddd26693a3f82
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/f9/04/24/195d24c0a127b8298b5aed16cc0d6b0a737501c1392b331099
  Building wheel for python-multipart (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for python-multipart (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for python-multipart: filename=python_multipart-0.0.5-py3-none-any.whl size=31670 sha256=d88b52d83fcdacc1e3766b1f70974dadba0810ae7a4ccb044d07b0fd7ccad505
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/9e/fc/1c/cf980e6413d3ee8e70cd8f39e2366b0f487e3e221aeb452eb0
  Building wheel for sentence-transformers (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for sentence-transformers (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for sentence-transformers: filename=sentence_transformers-0.3.8-py3-none-any.whl size=101996 sha256=0613ddbb80a2f8919670cb8d44dd36da64c0ba1148cd5897bc37acd2cd23812f
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/95/eb/10/39e6fdf924ec09c8f177547a8b3976c624632e180d36e1cb56
  Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pyyaml (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pyyaml: filename=PyYAML-5.3.1-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=572460 sha256=fe06c85293d0da96cd6549d2a4a58943be2fe83fd3b49aca52dd4fda53d83b37
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/13/90/db/290ab3a34f2ef0b5a0f89235dc2d40fea83e77de84ed2dc05c
  Building wheel for sacremoses (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for sacremoses (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for sacremoses: filename=sacremoses-0.0.43-py3-none-any.whl size=893259 sha256=2719f54ea8eb2169e3adaac106ee9bcfb745ebd760fc5501ff5409b7ae05e7ed
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/7b/78/f4/27d43a65043e1b75dbddaa421b573eddc67e712be4b1c80677
  Building wheel for pypika (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for pypika (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for pypika: filename=PyPika-0.43.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=46526 sha256=e925a4b5f0259a4a0a9c1edde2db202e25badc79af45b44ec407e1e3b10e4659
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/a1/3c/30/39e72a8618e7f74681b093f39fc7df9db5a5d9a5343598a75f
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for psycopg2 (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for psycopg2: filename=psycopg2-2.8.6-cp38-cp38-linux_x86_64.whl size=501094 sha256=d985613330e1098ab8993a77e2de35b79f5f4cdee8394303d60b2981383c15ab
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/70/5e/69/8a020d78c09043156a7df0b64529e460fbd922ca065c4b795c
  Building wheel for nltk (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for nltk (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for nltk: filename=nltk-3.5-py3-none-any.whl size=1434675 sha256=ac4d0bceab3793ae0476363feeb4cf56db8ecd34106377f6ed1a355f701c4328
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/ff/d5/7b/f1fb4e1e1603b2f01c2424dd60fbcc50c12ef918bafc44b155
  Building wheel for promise (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for promise (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
  Created wheel for promise: filename=promise-2.3-py3-none-any.whl size=21494 sha256=c801735e97a177280e9650c6fe518ab355ff8f8d77753d31c8b9c61d404d0117
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/54/aa/01/724885182f93150035a2a91bce34a12877e8067a97baaf5dc8
Successfully built tortoise-orm python-multipart sentence-transformers pyyaml sacremoses pypika psycopg2 nltk promise
Installing collected packages: pydantic, starlette, MarkupSafe, jinja2, orjson, uvloop, websockets, click, h11, httptools, uvicorn, async-exit-stack, idna, dnspython, email-validator, six, rx, promise, graphql-core, graphql-relay, aniso8601, graphene, python-multipart, pyyaml, certifi, chardet, urllib3, requests, aiofiles, ujson, itsdangerous, async-generator, fastapi, pycparser, cffi, bcrypt, passlib, regex, tqdm, filelock, protobuf, sentencepiece, pyparsing, packaging, joblib, sacremoses, tokenizers, transformers, ecdsa, pyasn1, rsa, cryptography, python-jose, pypika, iso8601, typing-extensions, aiosqlite, aerich, tortoise-orm, makefun, pyjwt, sniffio, httpcore, rfc3986, httpx, httpx-oauth, fastapi-users, sqlalchemy, asyncpg, psycopg2, databases, PyMySQL, aiomysql, threadpoolctl, scipy, scikit-learn, nltk, sentence-transformers
ERROR: After October 2020 you may experience errors when installing or updating packages. This is because pip will change the way that it resolves dependency conflicts.

We recommend you use --use-feature=2020-resolver to test your packages with the new resolver before it becomes the default.

sentence-transformers 0.3.8 requires transformers<3.4.0,>=3.1.0, but you'll have transformers 3.4.0 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed MarkupSafe-1.1.1 PyMySQL-0.9.2 aerich-0.3.2 aiofiles-0.6.0 aiomysql-0.0.20 aiosqlite-0.16.0 aniso8601-7.0.0 async-exit-stack-1.0.1 async-generator-1.10 asyncpg-0.21.0 bcrypt-3.2.0 certifi-2020.6.20 cffi-1.14.3 chardet-3.0.4 click-7.1.2 cryptography-3.2.1 databases-0.4.0 dnspython-2.0.0 ecdsa-0.14.1 email-validator-1.1.1 fastapi-0.61.1 fastapi-users-3.0.6 filelock-3.0.12 graphene-2.1.8 graphql-core-2.3.2 graphql-relay-2.0.1 h11-0.9.0 httpcore-0.12.0 httptools-0.1.1 httpx-0.16.1 httpx-oauth-0.3.4 idna-2.10 iso8601-0.1.13 itsdangerous-1.1.0 jinja2-2.11.2 joblib-0.17.0 makefun-1.9.4 nltk-3.5 orjson-3.4.3 packaging-20.4 passlib-1.7.4 promise-2.3 protobuf-3.13.0 psycopg2-2.8.6 pyasn1-0.4.8 pycparser-2.20 pydantic-1.7.2 pyjwt-1.7.1 pyparsing-2.4.7 pypika-0.43.0 python-jose-3.2.0 python-multipart-0.0.5 pyyaml-5.3.1 regex-2020.10.28 requests-2.24.0 rfc3986-1.4.0 rsa-4.6 rx-1.6.1 sacremoses-0.0.43 scikit-learn-0.23.2 scipy-1.5.3 sentence-transformers-0.3.8 sentencepiece-0.1.94 six-1.15.0 sniffio-1.2.0 sqlalchemy-1.3.20 starlette-0.13.6 threadpoolctl-2.1.0 tokenizers-0.9.2 tortoise-orm-0.16.17 tqdm-4.51.0 transformers-3.4.0 typing-extensions-3.7.4.3 ujson-3.2.0 urllib3-1.25.11 uvicorn-0.11.8 uvloop-0.14.0 websockets-8.1
Removing intermediate container 495de7e00ea1
 ---> 1f5ebe87ad1b
Step 6/7 : COPY ./app /app
 ---> 1a8304d31427
Step 7/7 : CMD uvicorn --host=0.0.0.0 app.main:app
 ---> Running in 312a5918910b
Removing intermediate container 312a5918910b
 ---> f40ca2cf01f4
Successfully built f40ca2cf01f4
Successfully tagged discusearch_web:latest
Creating network "discusearch_mynetwork" with driver "bridge"
Pulling db (postgres:11)...
11: Pulling from library/postgres
babf97a3f00a: Pull complete
0526c44df6ea: Pull complete
b2466ee00e96: Pull complete
77c605d60192: Pull complete
76b14ab41842: Pull complete
440f557fff31: Pull complete
30bba27806f4: Pull complete
a4e155509054: Pull complete
4eb8e47accdf: Pull complete
de89dffa0b49: Pull complete
9b7294df4e25: Pull complete
1ddd01426f4a: Pull complete
b846471366bf: Pull complete
ee5883575014: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:d441bf645a1dcd2b4429d916c276d4c01299ee16b7a0e0f3d0baa846cbd4ee07
Status: Downloaded newer image for postgres:11
Creating discusearch_db_1 ... done
Creating DiscuSearchFastAPI ... done
Attaching to discusearch_db_1, DiscuSearchFastAPI
db_1   | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db_1   | This user must also own the server process.
db_1   | 
db_1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db_1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db_1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db_1   | 
db_1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
db_1   | 
db_1   | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db_1   | creating subdirectories ... ok
db_1   | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db_1   | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db_1   | selecting default timezone ... Etc/UTC
db_1   | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db_1   | creating configuration files ... ok
db_1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
db_1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db_1   | syncing data to disk ... ok
db_1   | 
db_1   | WARNING: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db_1   | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db_1   | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db_1   | 
db_1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db_1   | 
db_1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db_1   | 
db_1   | waiting for server to start....2020-11-02 04:20:16.680 UTC [45] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:16.707 UTC [46] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-11-02 04:20:16 UTC
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:16.712 UTC [45] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server started
db_1   | CREATE DATABASE
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/*
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:17.135 UTC [45] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db_1   | waiting for server to shut down....2020-11-02 04:20:17.136 UTC [45] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:17.144 UTC [45] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 52) exited with exit code 1
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:17.147 UTC [47] LOG:  shutting down
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:17.157 UTC [45] LOG:  database system is shut down
db_1   |  done
db_1   | server stopped
db_1   | 
db_1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:17.271 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:17.272 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:17.274 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:17.292 UTC [63] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2020-11-02 04:20:17 UTC
db_1   | 2020-11-02 04:20:17.299 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
DiscuSearchFastAPI | INFO:     Started server process [6]
DiscuSearchFastAPI | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
DiscuSearchFastAPI | ERROR:    Traceback (most recent call last):
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 526, in lifespan
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     async for item in self.lifespan_context(app):
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 467, in default_lifespan
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     await self.startup()
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 502, in startup
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     await handler()
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tortoise/contrib/fastapi/__init__.py", line 92, in init_orm
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     await Tortoise.init(config=config, config_file=config_file, db_url=db_url, modules=modules)
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tortoise/__init__.py", line 555, in init
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     await cls._init_connections(connections_config, _create_db)
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tortoise/__init__.py", line 385, in _init_connections
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     await connection.create_connection(with_db=True)
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tortoise/backends/asyncpg/client.py", line 94, in create_connection
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     self._pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(None, password=self.password, **self._template)
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 398, in _async__init__
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     await self._initialize()
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 426, in _initialize
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     await first_ch.connect()
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 125, in connect
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     self._con = await self._pool._get_new_connection()
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 468, in _get_new_connection
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     con = await connection.connect(
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1718, in connect
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     return await connect_utils._connect(
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 674, in _connect
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     raise last_error
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 663, in _connect
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     con = await _connect_addr(
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/asyncpg/connect_utils.py", line 632, in _connect_addr
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     tr, pr = await asyncio.wait_for(
DiscuSearchFastAPI |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 498, in wait_for
DiscuSearchFastAPI |     raise exceptions.TimeoutError()
DiscuSearchFastAPI | asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
DiscuSearchFastAPI | 
DiscuSearchFastAPI | ERROR:    Application startup failed. Exiting.
DiscuSearchFastAPI | INFO:     Started server process [6]
DiscuSearchFastAPI | INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
```

Comment: My guess is the database takes a bit longer to start have a look at the docker [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for a common solution

Comment: I did find this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62197514/how-to-make-sure-the-database-has-been-created-before-application-connection?noredirect=1&lq=1 which features similar problem and redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y. I tried solution from the last link but as far as I can tell it had no meaningful impact on the error. I will try to increase delays I guess, but so far it's not solving the problem.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I also started getting the same error out of no where one day.

Comment: @VladislavVaradinov I don't really remember and at some point I moved database out of docker-compose. Following my own edit at the top, probably starting again from some working example would be the way.

By the way, if you just started getting errors in a working project, check versions since few months ago there was some significant rework.